# Is there any way to load a nib without using the class UINib?

Tags: ios, swift

The documentation states that `UINib` will throw and exception if `nibName` is not found.

```swift
let nib = UINib(nibName: , bundle: )
```

Unfortunately, it's not marked with `throws` so I cannot capture the error.

Checking the `.xib` file exists using the following

```swift
FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: )
```

The documentation for `fileExists(atPath: )` highlights [race conditions, file permissions and security](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/RaceConditions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002585). So the best way to move forward with file introspection is to just load the file and handle any erros loading the file rather than check it's location first.

So is there any way to load a nib without using the class UINib?

Comment: why you care if you already know that it shipped / not with package

Comment: Why you want to check if it exists? Isn't exception an indication that it doesn't exist?

Comment: I'm building a module. So I don't already know if it's with the package. Being a module, I would prefer to prevent crashes.

Comment: You can use `if let file = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("XibName", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first { print(file)}` to load file. This will throw an exception if file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should use UINib, it will be a lot simpler.  You just have to wrap it with some ObjcTry method like the solution presented in [Swift Error Handling For Methods That Do Not Throw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994538/swift-error-handling-for-methods-that-do-not-throw)

Comment: so this is better for a duplicate ?